# while loop not working while reading file in sh

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, sh

I have the following shell script deployed in my Jenkinsfile

```
withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/busybox:/kaniko']) {
  sh """#!/busybox/sh
    cat "images2.txt"
    cat "images2.txt" | while read line || [ -n "\$line" ]; do
      fields=(\$line)
      echo "FROM \${fields[0]}" | /kaniko/executor --dockerfile /dev/stdin --destination \${fields[1]}
    done
"""
}
```

I have to escape the `$` since its inside a Jenkinsfile otherwise Groovy doesnt expect it.

The contents of `images2.txt` are:

```
docker.io/prom/blackbox-exporter:v0.14.0 eu.gcr.io/development/infra/monitoring/blackbox-exporter:v0.14.0
docker.io/busybox:1.30.0 eu.gcr.io/development/infra/monitoring/busybox:1.30.0
```

When the pipeline runs, I get the error

```
/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/test-job@tmp/durable-9cce3aab/script.sh: line 4: syntax error: unexpected "(" (expecting "done")
```

I have also tried doing something like this

```
sh """#!/busybox/sh
input="images2.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
  do
    fields=(\$line)
    echo "FROM \${fields[0]}" | /kaniko/executor --dockerfile /dev/stdin --destination \${fields[1]}
  done < "\$input" 
"""
```

But the result is the same. Any idea what might be wrong here ?

Comment: `sh` doesn't support arrays. No `fields=( ... )`, no `${fields[0]}`.

Comment: ...and even in bash, `array=( $anything )` is buggy and should never be used; see [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29).

Comment: Anyhow, you only have two fields, so you don't need an array in the first place; use `while read -r field1 field2 rest; do echo "FROM $field1" | ...whatever... "$field2"`; `read` itself takes one argument per variable to split fields into (everything remaining goes into the last named variable, hence using `rest` so you don't get extra cruft in `field2`).

Comment: Make sure `images2.txt` uses Unix line endings, and you won't need the `|| [ -n "$line" ]` hack at all.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Charles Duffy's recommendation, I implemented

```
sh """#!/busybox/sh
cat "images2.txt" | while read field1 field2 rest; do
  echo "FROM \$field1" | /kaniko/executor --dockerfile /dev/stdin --destination \$field2
done
"""
```

and it worked perfectly.